# How to clear interval in functional component if interval is set in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that starting an interval in `useEffect` is easy to be cleared like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(some function, time);
   return () => clearInterval(interval)
})
```

But what if i have to set an interval inside a function, how to clear interval in that case, or simply i don't have to??

```
const startGame = () => {
  const interval = setInterval(some function, time);
}

useEffect(() => {
  startGame()
})
```

Comment: You can use `clearInterval(interval)` anywhere whether in. a function  or useEffect. What does it have to do with it?

Comment: `const interval = setInterval(interval);` inside `setInterval` you need to provide a callback not the same assignment

Comment: @ABGR

I am creating a game and i have to set some intervals that should work at the start of the game in a  function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use thw *useEffect* hook to clear the interval

```
   import React, { useEffect } from "react";

    const Timer = () => {
      const interval = React.useRef();
      const startGame = () => {
        interval.current = setInterval(() => {
          //code
        }, 3000);
      };
      React.useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
          clearInterval(interval.current);
        };
      }, []);
    };
    
    export default Timer;
```

Comment: what if i have several ```setInterval``` statments?

Comment: You can assign them to different properties of  interval object like interval.a, interval.b and so on and then clear them too separately

Comment: @CodeEagle I'm not too sure if this will clear though. Does it work btw? My concern primarily is on this: when you `clearInterval(interval.current);`, you clear one value (let's say whatever, `interval.current` holds at that time, say number 15. But the ones that are assigned already may lead to infinite loop. Another concern is `useEffect ` doesn't have any dependency here so it wouldn't be called after the initial load.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Timer = () => {
  
    let interval = useRef();
    const startGame = () => {
      interval.current  = setInterval(() => {
        // your code
      }, 1000)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      startGame();
      return () => clearInterval(interval.current)
    })
 
    return (
      // your jsx code;
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

Comment: const interval = setInterval(interval); inside setInterval you need to provide a callback not the same assignment

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```js
var ctr = 0, interval = 0;
var startGame1 = () => {
  ctr++;
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log("hello")
  if(ctr>=5){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }else{
   interval = setInterval(()=>{startGame1()}, 1000);
  }
}

startGame1()
```

Comment: The interval should update the game, so no condition needed to clear it in the game, i need to clear it in ```useEffect```

Comment: I think you wanna check out @urvashi's answer above then. Does that not work?